# "MathJax so slow and stuck when editing in SE."

Tags: phrase-choice

> MathJax so slow and stuck when editing in SE.

How do I rephrase this sentence?

Maybe *when I'm editing* is the right choice. Is my using wrong?

Is the following preferable / more correct?

> MathJax is so slow and so stuck when I'm editing in SE?

Comment: The first one sounds like MathJax is used to edit SE. How about "MathJax slows right down while I am editing in SE"

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need the "is", so "MathJax is so slow..." But now "stuck" is a problem because "MathJax is stuck when..." would be wrong, so we need another verb: "MathJax is so slow and gets stuck..." Then, as others have pointed out, "editing" suggests that MathJax is doing the editing, so you need the I'm. "MathJax is so slow and gets stuck when I'm editing in SE".

On the other hand "so slow" is informal so perhaps you don't have to be so precise. You do need the "is", though.